# Replace script not working with unicode txt files

Tags: excel, vba, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to use the following code to replace all tabs with commas in a text file:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const TristateTrue = -1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\CSV.txt", ForReading, TristateTrue)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
strTab = vbTab

strText = Replace(strText, strTab, ",")

objFile.Close

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\CSV.txt", ForWriting, TristateTrue)

objFile.Write strText

objFile.Close
```

However, when running this for the attached [file](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B4BqRJWgBEa2bVM1X19EVWdKU1k), I get the error:

Line 17
Char 1
Invalid procedure call or argument

This file is a unicode txt file created from Excel.

If I open the file and save in UTF-8 format, my code works correctly. However, I cannot find a way to do this conversion in code without garbled results.

Could anyone help me get my code working with the original unicode text file OR find a way of using executable code (vba/batch) to convert the file to UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Help

> Opens a specified file and returns a TextStream object that can be used to read from, write to, or append to the file.
>
> `object.OpenTextFile(filename[, iomode[, create[, format]]])`
>
> **object**
>
> Required. Object is always the name of a FileSystemObject.
>
> **filename**
>
> Required. String expression that identifies the file to open.
>
> **iomode**
>
> Optional. Can be one of three constants: ForReading, ForWriting, or ForAppending.
>
> **create**
>
> Optional. Boolean value that indicates whether a new file can be created if the specified filename doesn't exist. The value is True if a new file is created, False if it isn't created. If omitted, a new file isn't created.
>
> **format**
>
> Optional. One of three Tristate values used to indicate the format of the opened file. If omitted, the file is opened as ASCII.

You are specifying `Create` with `TristateTrue` not `Format`.

You can omit the False below (False is the default) but NOT the `,`. Positional parameters must be specified in order, missing ones with a comma. Trailing commas can also be omitted.

> objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\CSV.txt", ForWriting, **False,** TristateTrue)

Comment: Wow i'm annoyed I missed that, thanks! I would have thought TristateTrue on Create would have thrown up an error as it's not boolean? No matter though as it works perfectly now!